# Problem of "Please point me at a wall." with turtlebot_calibration

Tags: calibration, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a ROS newby attempting to bring up a TurtleBot with ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04.  I've got the laptop and TurtleBot configured and can get the turtlebot_dashboard going and drive the robot around with a keyboard using the keyboard teleop.  I can also apply power to the Kinect device and see the three requisite Microsoft USB devices with 'lsusb':

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

The problem I have is with turtlebot_calibration.  I get the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
turtlebot@turtlebot ~ $ roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http;//192.168.0.38;56954/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /kinect_laser/max_height
 * /kinect_laser/min_height
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /openni_launch/debayering
 * /openni_launch/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_launch/depth_mode
 * /openni_launch/depth_registration
 * /openni_launch/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_launch/image_mode
 * /openni_launch/image_time_offset
 * /openni_launch/rgb_frame_id
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /scan_to_angle/max_angle
 * /scan_to_angle/min_angle

NODES
  /
    kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_launch (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
    scan_to_angle (turtlebot_calibration/scan_to_angle.py)
    turtlebot_calibration (turtlebot_calibration/calibrate.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http;//192.168.0.38;11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [2132]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [2133]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [2139]
[ INFO] [1360034582.865846913]: Initializing nodelet with 2 worker threads.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [2199]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [2218]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [2240]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[scan_to_angle-7]: started with pid [2264]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[turtlebot_calibration-8]: started with pid [2266]
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/0f317c9e-6f42-11e2-a312-74f06d7d6e3b/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[ INFO] [1360034585.493648021]: [/openni_launch] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1360034585.494195015]: [/openni_launch] 1. device on bus 001:18 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00366910379111A'
[ WARN] [1360034585.498586615]: [/openni_launch] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1360034585.684649890]: [/openni_launch] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:18 with serial number 'A00366910379111A'
[ INFO] [1360034585.745636145]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1360034585.754150877]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034586.442313] has_gyro True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034586.526588] Estimating imu drift
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034586.829244] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034587.131364] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034587.433592] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034587.736142] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034588.038365] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034588.340482] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.598461] Please point me at a wall.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034588.642893] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.653256] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.721784] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.787651] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.855477] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.921614] Please point me at a wall.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034588.944915] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034588.985250] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.051861] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.119464] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.195161] Please point me at a wall.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034589.246879] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.257410] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.318238] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.392053] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.453150] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.519380] Please point me at a wall.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034589.548499] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.586282] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.653485] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.724938] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.797709] Please point me at a wall.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1360034589.850087] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.853053] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.921030] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034589.999481] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034590.056063] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1360034590.120422] Please point me at a wall.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output will continue until I hit ^C.  It never sees a wall.

I've tried moving the robot different distances from the wall, but nothing seems to change the results.  It always asks "Please point me at a wall."

Any ideas what may be wrong or how I may go about diagnosing and fixing this so that I can correctly calibrate the turtlebot?

Thanks,

Mike Thompson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54279/problem-of-%22please-point-me-at-a-wall.%22-with-turtlebot_calibration/) by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-02-04**:
Can you view the data from the Kinect?

**Comment by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on 2013-02-05**:
Yes, I can view both image and depth data from the Kinect following the instructions here: http://surenkum.blogspot.com/2012/06/getting-kinect-to-work.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here turned out to be topics not be remapped properly. This is now fixed in source ([see commit here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/commit/b6ed0f43511933045213267998a772a9e680623d)), version 2.0.2 should be released shortly and so debs will be updated in a few days.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-04**:
I've applied the changes, but the problem persists. I'm using Fuerte. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-06-04**:
I honestly have no idea what shape the Fuerte release is in. I only tried groovy, and would generally suggest using groovy at this point since releases into Fuerte are few and far between.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-05**:
I reverted back to the old config and made it work my modifying kinect.launch. So I guess the old config was appropriate on Fuerte. I don't want to switch to Groovy because making everything work took a lot of time, and I don't want to go through that process again, at least not yet!